# color a cell of a KendoUI grid via MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

In a ASP.Net MVC application I wish to show in a kendo grid column a cell () colored via a color I receive in the form #FFAABB from the controller... how can I do that?

can I just apply the color via style received in the viewbag or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is the color is going to be only one that is being passed from the Controller and if so then you can use Viewbag or a Static variable.

But if the colors are going to differ with each rows of the Grid then its better to pass them along the Model and use a template to set the color, please see a demo I created for the same: [Column Coloring from Model](http://dojo.telerik.com/@D_Learning/EruNe)